# How to make gRaphael assets visible to assets pipeline in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprockets, graphael

i've been looking on how to integrate gRaphael with Rails and been using this [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/graphael-rails)

From the gem i notice it has a class for the Rails Engine:

File graphael-rails.rb

```
module Graphael
  module Rails
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

    end
  end
end
```

And since the rails guides mention a similar behavior for jquery :

> 7 Adding Assets to Your Gems Assets can also come from external
>   sources in the form of gems.
>
> A good example of this is the jquery-rails gem which comes with Rails
>   as the standard JavaScript library gem. This gem contains an engine
>   class which inherits from Rails::Engine. By doing this, Rails is
>   informed that the directory for this gem may contain assets and the
>   app/assets, lib/assets and vendor/assets directories of this engine
>   are added to the search path of Sprockets.

I guess the files would be recognized adding `//= require Graphael` to my application.js, but it seems not, since i'm getting the error message `Sprockets::FileNotFound couldn't find file 'Graphael'` ...

What might i do for sprockets to recognize gRaphael?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The files are available under `raphael` according to the gem's directory structure: https://github.com/cschwartz/graphael-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts

Try

```
//= require raphael
```